# How to reduce the execution time of multiple models' inference on a large dataset in pyspark?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pyspark, pandas-udf

I have a pyspark data frame of a huge number of rows ( 80 million -100 million rows). I am inferencing a model on it to obtain the model score(probability) for each row. Like the below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def inference(df):

    col_names = [c for c in df.columns]

    @pandas_udf(returnType=T.DoubleType())
    def predict_pandas_udf(*features):
        X = pd.concat(features, axis=1)
        X.columns = col_names

        # Create a dataset
        ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(X))
        ds = ds.batch(1024)

       # Get model
        nn = keras.models.load_model(f'all_models/model_1')

        prob = nn.predict(ds)
        return pd.Series(prob[:, 0])

    df = df. \
            withColumn('probability', predict_pandas_udf(*(F.col(c) for c in df.columns )))
           
    return df



df=spark.table('p13n_features_explore.ss_ltr_low_confidence_pairs_with_features_amalgam')

scores=inference(df)
   
scores.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(f'gs://p13n-storage2/data/features/smart_subs/lcp_pairs_amalgam')
```

This code's entire execution, that is, till writing to a data path, is taking around 22 minutes.
I want to have ten models ensemble for it, i.e. inferencing ten models on it and taking the mean of the scores in the final, like the code below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def inference(df):

    col_names = [c for c in df.columns]

    @pandas_udf(returnType=T.DoubleType())
    def predict_pandas_udf(*features):
        X = pd.concat(features, axis=1)
        X.columns = col_names

        # Create a dataset
        ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(X))
        ds = ds.batch(1024)

        # Get model
        prob_scores_list=[]
        for i in range(1,11):
            nn = keras.models.load_model(f'all_models/model_{i}')
            prob = nn.predict(ds)
            prob_scores_list.append(prob[:, 0])
           
        prob_scores = np.array(prob_scores_list)    
        return pd.Series(prob_scores.mean(axis=0))

    df = df. \
            withColumn('probability', predict_pandas_udf(*(F.col(c) for c in df.columns )))
           
    return df



df=spark.table('p13n_features_explore.ss_ltr_low_confidence_pairs_with_features_amalgam')

scores=inference(df)
   
scores.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(f'gs://p13n-storage2/data/features/smart_subs/lcp_pairs_amalgam')
```

But this entire execution takes a massive amount of time; it takes around 5 hours. How can I make it executable in less than an hour? Can we remove the loop and somehow vectorize this implementation?

What are the various methods for making the multiple module ensemble inferencing on enormous data in pyspark faster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This need not be so complicated. Here's an concrete example of how you can do this.

First load all the models in a list. Broadcast the list. Access the list broadcasted variable's value using `value`. You can concatenate your features into an array as I have done below then do inference on samples one by one.
You could achieve the batch semantics by using mapPartition function on an rdd and then convert the result back to dataframe as shown below.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
import joblib
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


## Get the data_iris.csv from this location : https://github.com/dehaoterryzhang/Iris_Classification/tree/master/data
input_file = "../data/data_iris.csv"

initial_df = sqlContext.read.option("inferSchema", "true").csv(input_file, header=True)
initial_df.show(n=10, truncate=False)

X_train_df = initial_df.select(['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width'])
y_train_df = initial_df.select("species")

print("X_train_df features info")
X_train_df.show(n=3, truncate=False)
print("y_train_df label info")
y_train_df.show(n=3, truncate=False)

print("distinct classes in the dataset")
y_train_df.distinct().show(n=100, truncate=False)

all_columns = X_train_df.columns
X_train_df = X_train_df.withColumn("features_concat", F.array(all_columns))

all_columns_afterarray = X_train_df.columns

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

model = Sequential([
    Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)])

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, verbose=0)

keras_model_export_path = '../model_exported/keras_nn_iris_model.pkl'
## Uncomment below to export the trained model
# joblib.dump(model, keras_model_export_path, compress=9)


keras_model_loaded_from_path = joblib.load(keras_model_export_path)
model_clone_list = [ keras_model_loaded_from_path] * 10  ## just to simulate list of 10 models, the models are just copies one model

## Broadcasting the models so that they are available at the executor
broadcasted_model_clone_list = sc.broadcast(model_clone_list)


def different_inference(features_array):
    X = pd.DataFrame([features_array])
    X.columns = all_columns

    prediction_classification_scores_list = []
    # inference over all 10 models in a for loop
    for model_ii in broadcasted_model_clone_list.value:
        curr_result = model_ii.predict(X)
        prediction_classification_scores_list.append(curr_result[:, 0])

    prob_scores = np.array(prediction_classification_scores_list)
    final_result = pd.Series(prob_scores.mean(axis=0)).tolist()

    return final_result


different_inference_udf = F.udf(different_inference)

### Inferencing over only 10 rows
#predicted_df = X_train_df.limit(10).withColumn("prediction_scores", different_inference_udf(F.col("features_concat")))

print("Inference result from the 10 models")
#predicted_df.show(n=10, truncate=False)



def mapPartition_inference(partitioned_rows):

    features_array_list = []
    for row in partitioned_rows:
        features_array_list.append(row.features_concat)

    X = pd.DataFrame(features_array_list)
    X.columns = all_columns

    prediction_classification_scores_list = []
    # inference over all 10 models in a for loop
    for model_ii in broadcasted_model_clone_list.value:
        curr_result = model_ii.predict(X)
        prediction_classification_scores_list.append(curr_result[:, 0])

    prob_scores = np.array(prediction_classification_scores_list)
    final_result = pd.Series(prob_scores.mean(axis=0)).tolist()
    print("Hooray are we here!!!!!!!!!!!!!")

    constructed_result = []
    for jj in range(len(features_array_list)):
        constructed_result.append([features_array_list[jj], final_result[jj]])

    return iter(constructed_result)


partitioned_df = X_train_df.limit(30).repartition(10)

partition_predicted_df = partitioned_df.rdd.mapPartitions(mapPartition_inference).toDF(["features_concat", "prediction_avg_scores"])

print("Inference result from the 10 models using mapPartitions (optimized version)")
partition_predicted_df.show(n=30, truncate=False)
```

Output is as follows :

```
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+
|sepal_length|sepal_width|petal_length|petal_width|species|
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+
|5.1         |3.5        |1.4         |0.2        |setosa |
|4.9         |3.0        |1.4         |0.2        |setosa |
|4.7         |3.2        |1.3         |0.2        |setosa |
|4.6         |3.1        |1.5         |0.2        |setosa |
|5.0         |3.6        |1.4         |0.2        |setosa |
|5.4         |3.9        |1.7         |0.4        |setosa |
|4.6         |3.4        |1.4         |0.3        |setosa |
|5.0         |3.4        |1.5         |0.2        |setosa |
|4.4         |2.9        |1.4         |0.2        |setosa |
|4.9         |3.1        |1.5         |0.1        |setosa |
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+
only showing top 10 rows

X_train_df features info
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|sepal_length|sepal_width|petal_length|petal_width|
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|5.1         |3.5        |1.4         |0.2        |
|4.9         |3.0        |1.4         |0.2        |
|4.7         |3.2        |1.3         |0.2        |
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
only showing top 3 rows

y_train_df label info
+-------+
|species|
+-------+
|setosa |
|setosa |
|setosa |
+-------+
only showing top 3 rows

distinct classes in the dataset
+----------+
|species   |
+----------+
|virginica |
|versicolor|
|setosa    |
+----------+

Inference result from the 10 models using mapPartitions (optimized version)

+--------------------+---------------------+
|features_concat     |prediction_avg_scores|
+--------------------+---------------------+
|[5.2, 3.4, 1.4, 0.2]|0.6321244239807129   |
|[5.1, 3.8, 1.5, 0.3]|0.6290395855903625   |
|[4.3, 3.0, 1.1, 0.1]|0.5323924422264099   |
|[4.8, 3.4, 1.6, 0.2]|0.6239675879478455   |
|[4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1]|0.6233397722244263   |
|[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.3]|0.625523030757904    |
|[4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2]|0.5821532607078552   |
|[5.0, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2]|0.627651035785675    |
|[4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3]|0.5886028409004211   |
|[4.8, 3.0, 1.4, 0.1]|0.6058898568153381   |
|[5.4, 3.9, 1.3, 0.4]|0.6334523558616638   |
|[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]|0.6212030053138733   |
|[4.6, 3.6, 1.0, 0.2]|0.5346620678901672   |
|[4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2]|0.6045092344284058   |
|[4.8, 3.4, 1.9, 0.2]|0.6606692671775818   |
|[5.0, 3.4, 1.6, 0.4]|0.6499260663986206   |
|[4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2]|0.618742823600769    |
|[5.1, 3.7, 1.5, 0.4]|0.6369576454162598   |
|[5.4, 3.7, 1.5, 0.2]|0.6512832045555115   |
|[5.2, 3.5, 1.5, 0.2]|0.640670657157898    |
|[5.8, 4.0, 1.2, 0.2]|0.6450895667076111   |
|[5.7, 4.4, 1.5, 0.4]|0.6659770607948303   |
|[5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2]|0.6101197004318237   |
|[4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2]|0.5853733420372009   |
|[5.0, 3.0, 1.6, 0.2]|0.6513381004333496   |
|[5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4]|0.679506242275238    |
|[4.7, 3.2, 1.6, 0.2]|0.6218041181564331   |
|[5.7, 3.8, 1.7, 0.3]|0.7012595534324646   |
|[5.4, 3.4, 1.7, 0.2]|0.6839534640312195   |
|[5.1, 3.3, 1.7, 0.5]|0.6780367493629456   |
+--------------------+---------------------+
```