# Is there a way to cache or reuse PythonUDFRunner environment to reduce initialization overhead in Pyspark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am working on a Pyspark structured streaming application to invoke an UDF functionality on every event.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *  

@udf()
def process(payload):
    # Some API calls and custom processing of the event. Invoking the application code.
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("Stream-POC3")\
        .getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    # Create DataSet representing the stream of input events from kafka
    events_raw_df = ( spark\
        .readStream\
        .format("kafka")\
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)\
        .option(subscribeType, topics)\
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
        .load() \
        .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
    )
    
    events_udf_df = events_raw_df.select(process(col("value") ))
```

While running the above application, observed that the initialization time for the python udf is causing a huge overhead on the stream processing. Below are the observations and metrics for every task execution.

**PythonUDFRunner: Times: total = 5874, boot = 2167, init = 3268, finish = 439 in pyspark streaming.**
**Total Time (5874):**
This is the overall time taken for the Python UDF runner to execute. It includes the time for booting up, initialization, and finishing.

**Boot Time (2167):**
This is the time spent in bootstrapping or setting up the necessary environment for Python UDF execution.

**Init Time (3268):**
This represents the initialization time, which is the time taken to prepare and set up resources before the actual Python UDF execution.

**Finish Time (439):**
This is the time taken to finish and clean up after the Python UDF execution.

I am exploring various methods available to minimize python udf overhead or maybe cache it for subsequent jobs processing.
**Note: ** It is not possible to convert the existing application code to spark sql or df.

Comment: You can use mapPartition function to do heavy initialize once and do your processing per row and return of rows. I have provided an example of how to do it here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77033826/3238085