# Use spark to replace multi threading

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a task and it comprises following 3 steps:

1. Read ids from a column of a data lake table
2. Call third party API service to get data for each id
3. Collect and merge all data together and then write into a delta lake tablle

I used multi threading to call the API and a list to store results and merge elements together but it's so large and lead to an OOM error.

Here is my code:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def union_all(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)

def main():
    # STEP 1 - Read ids from a table
    ids = list(map(lambda row: row.idName, spark.sql(SQL.IDS).collect()))

    # STEP 2 - Calling API and processing data via the func test_api
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as executor:  # multi-threading
        results = list(filter(None, executor.map(test_api, ids)))

    # STEP 3 - Collect, merge and write 
    final_df = union_all(*results) 
    final_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").save("/temp_tables/test_api3")
```

How to do this using spark itself? Such as `rdd mapPartitions` or `spark sql select`? I am using `Spark 3` and `Python 11`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: here's an example using mapPartitions. In the mapPartition function, if you need to do a complicated connection setup, you can do it once and reuse the setup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77031314/how-to-reduce-the-execution-time-of-multiple-models-inference-on-a-large-datase

Comment: There is a naive approach of wrapping your API function in a [UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html) and using syntax like `df.withColumn("output", my_udf("id"))` - but there is a good chance you will overwhelm the API server doing this. Does your API allow for batched processing? Or do you absolutely have to run this row-by-row?

Comment: hi @mimocha Thanks for reminding me. The service does not support batch processing so that is the reason why I have to find such approach..

Comment: That is unfortunate. If you want to use the UDF approach you will need to make your UDF asynchronous - which I don't know how to do. If you have to process your data in python, my approach would be to do ETL in batches. `Collect unprocessed IDs` -> `get API results` -> `store on database`, repeat until complete. Not the most efficient use of spark, but if this is a one-off thing it should be fine. Otherwise, you should look into [alternatives.](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/performance-issue-with-pyspark-udf-function-calling-rest-api/m-p/6891/highlight/true#M2892)