# For PySpark, is it possible to ignore errors for some specific rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, error-handling, apache-sedona

I’m executing a query on a table using PySpark and incorporating some Apache Sedona functions within the query. However, the query encountered issues with certain rows, leading to an interruption. Unfortunately, it didn’t provide any information about the problematic row.

Is there a way to implement a `try except` mechanism that would allow me to bypass the problematic row and continue processing the remaining rows?

Comment: If you are using map operation, then instead you can use mapPartition and within that function you can implement your try catch and output that row's id in the result because map expects same number of output rows as input rows.

Comment: here's an example of how to write and use mapPartition function in pyspark . https://stackoverflow.com/a/77033826/3238085