# Avoiding for loop in PySpark with Machine Learning

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, scikit-learn

I have this for loop in PySpark that iterates over different products of a supermarket, but it takes a long time.

How to do this without using a for-loop?

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
for i in products:
    # selecting the products
    df = df.filter(F.col("product") == i)
    df_train = df.filter(F.col("pvp_discount").isin([0.2, 0.5, 0.75]))

    # exponential regression
    exp = LinearRegression().fit(X, np.log(Y_delta))
    exp_pred = np.exp(exp.predict(X_test))

    # preparing to add the predictions to my df
    schema_exp_delta = StructType([StructField("delta_exp_pred", DoubleType(), True)])
    exp_delta = spark.createDataFrame(exp_pred.tolist(), schema = schema_exp_delta)
    exp_delta = exp_delta.withColumn("row_idx", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())))

    df = df.join(exp_delta, df.row_idx == exp_delta.row_idx)
```

Comment: You can use `partitionBy` to partition by column values. and then write a mapPartition function which mimics the full training run within a single partition containing all the rows which have a partiticular column value. Here are few resources. https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-partitionby-example/

mapPartition example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77033826/3238085

Comment: @Tiago Could you please try using `df = df.filter(F.col("product").isin(products))` instead of `df = df.filter(F.col("product") == i)` and remove the for loop altogether and let the rest of the code as it is (of course make sure to indent it properly after removing the for loop). This will be more efficient than the for loop - just let us know if you are getting the expected result from this revision.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but are you sure the `LinearRegression()` you use comes from scikit-learn, and not from Spark ML?

Comment: @user238607 thank you! I tried that and it worked :)

Comment: @desertnaut yes! its from scikit-learn! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spark's built-in functions to group your data by product and apply the calculations to each group in parallel, without using a for-loop. One way to achieve this is by using the `groupBy` and `mapInPandas` functions.

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

# Define a UDF
@pandas_udf(schema_exp_delta, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def exponential_regression(pdf):
   X, Y = pdf[['x_col']], pdf[['y_col']]
   exp = LinearRegression().fit(X, np.log(Y))
   exp_pred = np.exp(exp.predict(X_test))
   schema_exp_delta = StructType([StructField("delta_exp_pred", DoubleType(), True)])
   exp_delta = spark.createDataFrame(exp_pred.tolist(), schema = schema_exp_delta)
   exp_delta = exp_delta.withColumn("row_idx", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())))
   return exp_delta

# Group the data and apply regression to each group
df = df.filter(F.col("pvp_discount").isin([0.2, 0.5, 0.75]))
df = df.groupby('product').apply(exponential_regression)
```