How to Perform Inference in Spark with an XGBoost Model Trained in scikit-learn?
I found one xgboost model which was trained using sklearn in native python.
How can I use that model to produce inference on new dataset in pyspark?
Apart from using UDFs, what other options do I have?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

here's an example I wrote a year back on using Keras Tensorflow model. so any model is possible.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77033826/3238085

xgboost model when trained on spark has this API for inference.predict_df = model.transform(test_df) link. the same is not available when i load a python based model

There's a deprecated spark_sklearn package but it was superseded by joblib-spark which unfortunately doesn't support distributed inference.
So I guess your best bet is to use pandas_udf:
@F.pandas_udf(returnType=DoubleType())
def predict(*cols):
    X = pd.concat(cols, axis=1) # cols is a tuple of pd.Series
    return pd.Series(model.predict_proba(X)[:, 1])

df_labeled = df.select(
    F.col('id'),
    predict(*column_names).alias('proba')
)

Of course there will still be some overhead here, but generally pandas_udf are efficient enough so that this overhead is negligible compared to the actual inference time (and Spark overhead)
