Spark PySpark Lazy Execution & Parallel Execution within an Object
I would like to execute a method within an object 5 times in parallel (on different data).
I have created an object with an init() that loads and preprocesses common data. I have a method that wraps together the rest of the steps in my execution. I presently run that method 5 times within a for loop safely. That method can be run in parallel because everything is independent.
I have parallelized my method as so:
def run_code_parallel(self):
    from threading import Thread
    threads = []
    for mrd, mrd_details in self.mrds.items():
        t = Thread(target=self.run_code, args=(mrd, mrd_details))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

It seems to be running in parallel.
I am fairly certain that the init() stage is lazily executed when needed during the first run of the method in the for loop.
I am concerned about the lazy init() when I run each thread.
Is Spark lazy execution smart/thread-safe enough to handle this or do I need to force everything in the init() to finish first?
Should I just use a count() on everything or another method? Is there a way to force run everything in the init() or do I have to run an action on everything I want to ensure is run?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77031314/how-to-reduce-the-execution-time-of-multiple-models-inference-on-a-large-datase
You can use an approach like above. Use mapPartition to run in parallel. The init step which will load model data will happen only once per partition and then the model will be inferred on each of the partition that you provide. Let me know if something is not clear.
